# Cypher - query missing parameter throws an exception

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have simple query with $login parameter

```
MATCH (user: User {login: $login})
RETURN user
```

when it is set to null in Neo4j Browser with

```
:param login => null
```

execution does not throw an exception and returns nothing which is expected.
However when I do not provide $login parameter following is thrown

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing
Expected parameter(s): login
```

Is there a way to proceed with query even if parameter **key** is not provided?

**P.S.**
I think the same issue is adressed [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2423#issuecomment-162258568) and according to the originator droping **WHERE** clause should make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a parameter isn't provided, you will always encounter an error when attempting to use that parameter.

However, you can get around this a bit with a little indirection. Consider passing a map structure as the parameter, which may contain entries for all of your other parameters, optional or not. As long as you're passing in the map parameter, your query should execute, and you can use either dot notation or index/key access into the map to use the parameters from the map.

For example:

```
:params  {params:{name:'Keanu Reeves'}}
```

We now have a $params parameter in scope, which is a map. Usage can be `$params.login` or `$params['login']`, both of which return null for the non-existing entry in the map.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was aware of that "workaround". If there is no other way then your answer is an ultimate solution :)